# Should we edit the tags of a solved question to classify it according to the real problem?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

Should we edit the tags of a solved question to classify it according to the real problem that the user had and not the one he thought he had?

Sometimes the user classify the question according to the evidences but after finding the solution it is clear that some tags are not related to the real problem. I may want to add new tags related to the problem too.

Answer (score 5):

I think the right practice is to add the tag (not replace it) because it'll help people facing the same issue as the asker (and don't know which tags are the right ones).

Comment: The problem is that you cannot add more tags when it already has 5, or two more tags, if it already has 4, etc. Replacing tags is not bad per se if it is done for good in my opinion. I did it many times myself as well as saw others doing it. There were many thankful OPs as an outcome. That being said, it really has to be done for good. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think this is useful. It is the reasonable grouping. It will be useful to overview the questions for the tags.

OPs frequently misunderstand the scope of the issues, but that is also normal because they come here to gain knowledge.

It is also possible that they were just unaware of some proper tags, and any help in that regard is more than appreciated, I believe.

Comment: But Samoth is right that deleting a tag that someone thought was related reduces the findability for others who don't know what the problem is.

Comment: AndrewC: I think proper tagging helps the most with finding a question. There are exceptions for sure, but I think that is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: I'm not arguing with that, I'm saying you should _delete_ tags with caution. I've come across two questions in the last week tagged with parsec where recursive descent parsing is not the solution. Removing the parsec tag from them would be correct logically but the incorrect action, since other people faced with the same problem in the same domain _are_ very likely to look under the parsec tag.

Comment: @AndrewC: yes, of course, deleting relevant tags without more relevant tags is unacceptable. That does not mean, a proper replacement is not good, however.

Comment: @LaszloPapp If you know the answer the tags are obvious to you but people who don't know the answer might think a different tag is relevant so do not necessarily delete them. I can'r see any problem with adding more correct tags

Comment: @Mark: do you have some data to back up "might" is the majority? I am certain that proper tags are easier to search, use and deal with. Do you have any data that incorrect tags are better? I do not think it is useful that someone added a wrong tag due to ignorance or other reason, which was not fixed later by anyone for the time, and it is not fixed. You are claiming that even if _one_ user made a mistake, we should keep existing wrong tags around. I personally claim the opposite. I will leave the decision and assessment with the technology experts, and not newbies. In doubts, leave a comment.

Comment: @LaszloPapp yes the asker thinks they are relevant - I agree not all but if they don't make sense to the asker why do they add them? Some will and should be deleted but we have to start by assuming they make some sense - and I do remove many tags

Comment: @LaszloPapp A proper replacement is unhelpful if you've deleted a way for a rational but  less knowledgable person to find the solution. As an example, if you removed the regex tag from all questions about parsing html, you would get many more duplicates than at present, even though those who know more about it see regex as an inappropriate tool to solve the problem. Html parsing is not a regex problem if you're knowledgable, but beginners will always try it, so the tag should stay. Ignorance is to some extent inevitable in askers, and the taxonomy should help askers find relevant questions.

Comment: @AndrewC: I am not sure what you argue about. What point are you trying to make? You disagree with my statements that the tag decision is better left with technology experts than newcomers to assess the situation, and in doubts, you can always leave a comment? I currently feel this discussion noisy, and I got lost a while ago about the point being made. It is not like bugtrackers are adhocly hacked up by newcomers either. There are the knowledge and trustworthy triangling people in there, in my opinion, for good. They also leave comments for clarification in doubts. This is not new. :)

Comment: Tag decisions are best left with users who understand both Stack Exchange and the problem domain well. I can distil my position to: Incoporate the OP's understanding of the problem when it's rational even if misguided, especially in the case of tagging with Y in the XY problem, in which case, leave the misguided Y tag on but also tag with Z, the appropriate solution technology.

Comment: (It's OK to delete random tags and misinterpreted tags, so removing `xcode` from a question about void in objective C is OK, and removing `java` from a question that starts "I know java already, but how do you do ___ in C#?" is appropriate, but leave `regex` on "how do I write a regex to parse this html here?" and leave `parsec` on "how can I fix this parsec parser - I can't get it to backtrack when the input string is not a palindrome". In short, take into account reasonable OP perceptions.

Comment: AndrewC: OK, so I interpret this as you would not leave it with the experts, and recommend commenting for them in doubts. That is fine. It is not the first disagreement; life will move on. :-)